# Como agrupar os microdados de pessoas do censo por residência?

Tags: r

Estou tentando responder a seguinte pergunta: Em quantos casais com filhos menores de 18 anos ambos pais trabalham fora?

Dado uma tabela `censo` de pessoas do censo 2010  (como [essa do Acre](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8740br0eougvt9n/AC.csv?dl=0)), primeira coisa que fiz foi filtrar a tabela por casais com filhos.

```
  censo <- read.csv("AC.csv", sep = "\t")

  # V5090 -- TIPO DE COMPOSIÇÃO FAMILIAR DAS FAMÍLIAS ÚNICAS E CONVIVENTES PRINCIPAIS
  #  1 - Casal sem filho(s)
  #  2 - Casal sem filho(s) e com parente(s)
  #  3 - Casal com filho(s)   <----------------------
  #  4 - Casal com filho(s) e com parente(s)  
  #  5 - Mulher sem cônjuge com filho(s)
  #  6 - Mulher sem cônjuge com filho(s) e com parente(s)
  #  7 - Homem sem cônjuge com filho(s)
  #  8 - Homem sem cônjuge com filho(s) e com parente(s)
  #  9 - Outro
  #  Branco

 censo_cf <- censo[which(censo$"V5090"  == 3),]
```

Depois filtrei para que pelo menos um dos filho tivesse menos de 18 anos:

```
# V6660 IDADE DO ÚLTIMO FILHO TIDO NASCIDO VIVO ATÉ 31 DE JULHO DE 2010:
censo_cf18 <- censo_cf[which(censo_cf$V6660  < 18),]
```

meu passo seguinte seria agrupar os entrevistados por domicílio (para depois verificar em quais domicílios ambos trabalhavam). Apesar de eu não ver isso documentado em nenhum lugar para o censo de 2010, segundo a [documentação do censo de 2000](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiP092RyY3JAhUMgZAKHXKjCsk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dpi.inpe.br%2Fgeocxnets%2Fwiki%2Flib%2Fexe%2Ffetch.php%3Fmedia%3Dwiki%3Atathi%3Adocumentacao_arquivo_de_dados_amostra.doc&usg=AFQjCNHSKykvaSU0E3a-qEKVyTK7xkKqOg&sig2=dB7G03LVBUTzRjC6_xpKXQ&bvm=bv.107467506,d.Y2I) (página 83) a variável `controle` seria:

> Identificação do domicílio

Assim, eu esperaria que dentro desse meu subconjuntos (casais com filhos) todos os domicílios tivessem pelo menos três entrevistados (marido, mulher e filho). Porém, somente três domicílios apresentavam isso:

```
# V0300 CONTROLE
table_V0300 <- table(censo_cf18$V0300)
pessoas_por_domicilio  <- table(table_V0300)
pessoas_por_domicilio

   1    2    3 
9340   57    3
```

Qual é o meu erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu erro está nesse parte:

```
censo_cf18 <- censo_cf[which(censo_cf$V6660  < 18),]
```

No momento que tu faz isso, tu está cortando fora 1) os homens (essa variável só existe para as mulheres) e os filhos. Portanto, a contagem de quantas vezes a variável `V0300` (que também é o controle no censo de 2010) está sendo feita de maneira errada, e por isso o resultado inesperado.

O que tu deve fazer é armazenar essa variável (`V0300`) dos casos que tu quer (domicílios com pelo menos 1 filho menor de 18 anos, formado por casal e filho(s) e onde o casal trabalha) e depois selecionar esses domicílios.

Segue um código (usando o pacote [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) e o banco que eu tenho da amostra já possui os labels, mas fica fácil adaptar para data.frame e sem os labels):

```
# Primeiro filtro - Pegar o código das residências dos casais com filhos

Filtro1 <- dados[V5090 == 'Casal com filho(s)', V0300]

# Segundo filtro - Pegar, dos casais com filhos, as mães que tem filhos com menos de 18 anos

Filtro2 <- dados[V0300 %in% Filtro1 & V6660 < 18, V0300]

# Agora, pegar somente o responsável ou seu conjuge:

temp <- dados[V0300 %in% Filtro2 & V0502 %in% c('Pessoa responsável pelo domicílio', 'Cônjuge ou companheiro(a) de sexo diferente', 'Cônjuge ou companheiro(a) do mesmo sexo'), .(V0300, PessoaTrabalhando = V0641 == 'Sim')] # Aqui já pego só as variáveis de interesse.

# Terceiro filtro - Pegar, dos casais com filhos e com pelo menos 1 filho com menos de 18 anos, os que ambos trabalham.

Filtro3 <- temp[, .(PessoasTrabalhando = sum(PessoaTrabalhando)), by = V0300][PessoasTrabalhando == 2, V0300]

# Agora sim da para fazer as análises

novosdados <- dados[V0300 %in% Filtro3, ]
novosdados[, .(N = .N), by = V0300][, table(N)]

# Resultado em Porto Alegre:
# N
#    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13 
# 1570 1139  397  141   52   17   13    6    1    1    1
```

Só lembrando que os dados da amostra devem ser ponderados pela variável `V0010`. **Se não me engano**, o peso do domicílio/família é o mesmo que o do responsável. Aproveitando, podes baixar a documentação do Censo 2010 [nesse link](ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2010/Resultados_Gerais_da_Amostra/Microdados/Documentacao.zip) (FTP do próprio IBGE).

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde rcoster e celacanto. Obrigado para sua conversa, resolveu uma das minhas dúvidas.

Gostaria contribuir que suas soluções ignoram famílias secundárias, ex. a família da filha convivendo com a família das pais. Neste caso, a família primária tem V5040=1 e a família secundária V5040=2. V5090=2, "casal com filhos" somente se aplica para a familia primária; para as outras precisa V5100=2. Em outras palavras, suas soluções deveriam ainda incluir as famílias secundárias (com a maior probabilidade de ter filhos<18 anos).

Os membros de uma família no mesmo domicílio (V0300) estão agrupados pelo V5020. Agrupando somente pelo V0300 ignora as limites entre famílias. "N" na solução do Rcoster é o número de pessoas por domicílio? Os números altos deixam me pensar em domicílios de duas famílias.

Para a família do responsável do domicílio, V0502 IN (1,2,3) é suficiente para identificar ambos os pais. Para a família secundária, deve agrupar pelo V0300 e e V5020 e testar se a mãe e mais uma pessoa tem V5090=2. Em domicílios de quatro gerações poderia dar errado, mas aqui acaba minha paixão para genealogia :-)